# for each on post from form not submitting correctly

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to loop thorough a form and submit the values to the database. It seems to work, except for that it tries to include the submit button itself into the database and so throws an error (as it doesnt exist in the DB) -  it still submits the other data to the correct fields. I tried adding in an if statement to avoid submitting the submit button values, which does indeed remove it (as when I print to the results it doesn't show and doesn't throw the error), but it stops the other values submitting to the database. I tried the below:

```
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){
    if($key!==='btnSubmit') {
$db->query($db->prepare("UPDATE `db-table` SET ".$key."= %s WHERE id= %d", $value, $selectedProduct));
}
```

Any ideas how to get around this is appreciated.

Comment: Wrong comparison

Comment: You can't have `!===`. You probably want `!==`. Comparisons are limited to two or three characters. See manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: First,check all post parameters using echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST); or print_r($_REQUEST);die;

Comment: also why `foreach()`, when you can update multiple columns in one single query....?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: It's also arguably vulnerable to over-posting attacks, unless it's not actually a problem for the query to be able to update every field in the table without any validation.

Comment: And as the commenter above says, you can do this much more efficiently in a single UPDATE statement. It would also help us if you told us exactly which database engine you're using, and which PHP library you're using to connect to it.

Comment: @Andreas - ah of course. I missed that. Noob mistake thanks!

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie i was using foreach() as i need to loop through the form to which is built from data that could have a columns added to it (by the user) over time and so the amount of columns could vary. This may not be the best solution (I'm fairly new to php so open to any other suggestion that may work better). Im using mysql, myphp admin and connecting to second db through on wordpress platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inarray method to skip certain fields from the $_POST data as given below

```
$skipKeys = array(
                    'btnSubmit',
                    // add more fields if needed
                 );

foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){

        if(!in_array($key,$skipKeys)){
            $db->query(
                $db->prepare(
                "UPDATE `db-table` SET ".$key."= %s WHERE id= %d", $value, $selectedProduct
                )
            );
        }

}
```